# How do I post a snippet to a slack thread?

Tags: slack

I want to post a snippet to a thread in slack, not the main channel.  I can't figure out how to do this in the Windows x64 client.  Any thoughts? Is it possible in another client?

Comment: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204145658-Create-a-snippet

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, that article does not help me--the methods outlined do not work in a thread in the windows app.  Can you offer more complete information?

Comment: Seems this works in the Mac client but not Windows?

Answer (score 8):

You are not directly shown the option to post a snippet or an image in a thread. But there is a workaround for this.
Steps

- Post the snippet/image in the channel or DM (I DM myself for this and delete it later)
- Copy Link to snippet/image
- Post the link in the desired thread. Slack shows a preview to the snippet/image in the thread itself as if it has been posted in the channel/DM as a normal snippet/image

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://medium.com/@brad.robertson/slack-threading-failure-threadfail-977859586d5a) you can't:

> You can’t add images (we post screenshots within conversations ALL THE TIME), run any slash commands, or add code snippets.

It's sad really... I use threads a lot but they have some usability concerns.

Comment: Agreed, threads seem like they were implemented without the UX team/lead, and rushed out the door. Threads should be first class citizens, but aren't thus making them a feature I just want to disable.

Comment: It seems images in threads are now supported.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the latest MacOS desktop version still doesn't allow you to post snippets to threads. I'm currently just using the web version which does support that.

Comment: OP is asking about Windows client.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just simply to post a message with the designated piece of code wrapped in triple single quotation marks ```example code```? 
It works the same here in the forum.